# Scipy.stats.gaussian_kde gives a pdf that is outside the range (0,1)

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, gaussian

An estimated pdf should only contain values from 0 to 1, so why does this toolbox estimate values all the way up to 12?

[image]

Comment: Also, is this type of question better for stackexchange CrossValidation?

Comment: *"An estimated pdf should only contain values from 0 to 1..."*  That is not correct.  The *PDF* is the probability *density* function.  Prbability densities can exceed 1.  It is the *integral* of the PDF on an interval [a, b] that can not exceed 1.  And yes, this is probably better on CrossValidated, and I'm sure there are many duplicates of the question there (as well as here on Stackoverflow).